# MongoDB Resync Failure

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongodb-replica-set

We have a shard server with 4 shard PSA Architecture. The overall DB size is around 5Tb. And one of the shard  secondary service have failed we started resyc from primary.
We are facing an issue when i am trying to resync data from a primary to secondary.

MongoDB Version 4.0.18

DataSize for that Shard:  571Gb

Oplog Size : Deault

**Error Message:**
2020-10-06T08:57:57.165+0530 I REPL     [replication-339] We are too stale to use host:port as a sync source. Blacklisting this sync source because our last fetched timestamp: Timestamp(1601947649, 446) is before their earliest timestamp: Timestamp(1601951946, 330) for 1min until: 2020-10-06T08:58:57.165+0530

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an initial sync to the dead node. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-sync/#initial-sync.

Comment: We have started sync from first only. Even though it print the same error. We have tried for multiple time for syncing.